# Mysql Reference subquery result in parent where clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

In our school, when a student is good, they get given a virtual pound (or dollar) which is stored in a database.

This is my query:

```
SELECT s.chosen_name, s.chosen_surname, s.regId, s.admission_number, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(a.pounds_amount) 
        FROM tbl_pounds_log a 
        WHERE a.student_id=l.student_id
    ) AS total_pounds, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(b.pounds_amount) 
        FROM tbl_pounds_log b 
        WHERE b.student_id=l.student_id 
        AND b.staff_id=:staffId 
        AND b.action_timestamp>(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600) 
    ) AS available_pounds 
FROM TBL_student s 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pounds_log l 
    ON l.student_id=s.admission_number 
WHERE ((s.chosen_name LIKE :termOne AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termTwo) 
        OR (s.chosen_name LIKE :termThree AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termFour))
    AND (total_pounds>=:lowerPoundLimit 
        AND total_pounds<=:upperPoundLimit) 
GROUP BY s.admission_number 
ORDER BY s.chosen_surname ASC, s.chosen_name ASC  
LIMIT 0,10
```

(I'm using PHP PDO to perform the query hence the :text placeholders).

I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to the WHERE condition in the parent query.

Where it says:

```
... AND (total_pounds>=:lowerPoundLimit and total_pounds<=:upperPoundLimit)
```

The total_pounds field is a column result of a subquery, however when I run the query it keeps coming up with:

```
Unknown column 'total_pounds' in 'where clause'
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the alias names is not yet available when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.  The problem should  be solved by moving the subqueries from the `SELECT` clause into `JOIN` clauses like this:

```
SELECT s.chosen_name, s.chosen_surname, s.regId, s.admission_number, 
       total_pounds.pound_amount as total_pounds,
       available_pounds.pound_amount as available_pounds
FROM TBL_student s
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT student_id, SUM(pounds_amount) AS pound_amount 
   FROM tbl_pounds_log
   GROUP BY student_id) AS total_pounds
ON total_pounds.student_id = s.admission_number 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT student_id, SUM(b.pounds_amount) AS pound_amount
   FROM tbl_pounds_log 
   WHERE b.staff_id=:staffId 
   AND b.action_timestamp>(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600)
   GROUP BY student_id) as available_pounds  
ON available_pounds.student_id = s.admission_number
WHERE ((s.chosen_name LIKE :termOne AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termTwo) 
        OR (s.chosen_name LIKE :termThree AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termFour))
    AND (total_pounds.pound_amount >= :lowerPoundLimit 
        AND total_pounds.pound_amount <= :upperPoundLimit) 
GROUP BY s.admission_number 
ORDER BY s.chosen_surname ASC, s.chosen_name ASC  
LIMIT 0,10
```

It is also seems possible to write the query without subqueries:

```
SELECT s.chosen_name, s.chosen_surname, s.regId, s.admission_number,
       SUM(tp.pounds_amount) AS total_pounds
       SUM(ap.pounds_amount) AS available pounds
FROM tbl_students s
LEFT JOIN tbl_pounds_log tp
ON tp.student_id = s.admission_number
LEFT JOIN tbl_pounds_log ap
ON ap.student_id = tp.student_id
AND ap.staff_id = tp.staff_id
AND ap.staff_id = :staffId
AND ap.action_timestamp = tp.action_timestamp
AND ap.action_timestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600)
WHERE s.chosen_name LIKE :termOne AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termTwo
OR s.chosen_name LIKE :termThree AND s.chosen_surname LIKE :termFour
GROUP BY s.admission_number, s.name, s.regId, s.admission_number
HAVING SUM(tp.pounds_amount) BETWEEN upperPoundLimit AND lowerPoundLimit
ORDER BY s.chosen_surname, s.chosen_name
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the two queries in relation to returned results? Thanks again :)

Comment: I think they should return the same results, but lacking data I have not been able to test them.

Comment: Thanks again, I've given the bottom one a test and it works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to avoid subqueries may be the 'real' solution (it may be possible to join tables and GROUP BY results)

Anyway, since you can't refer to 'total_pounds' in the WHERE clause, an easy solution is to repeat the subquery. This is ugly, but maybe query optimizer and/or your server's cache (if enable) will avoid executing 2 times each subquery...