# mariadb most efficient way to select several columns from a subquery

Tags: mariadb, subquery

I'm generating a table which will in turn be used to format several different statistics and graphs.

Some columns of this table, are a result of subqueries which use a nearly identical structure. My query works, but it is very inefficient even in a simplified example like the following one.

```
SELECT
o.order,
o.date,
c.clienttype,
o.producttype,
(SELECT date FROM orders_interactions LEFT JOIN categories WHERE order=o.order AND category=3) as completiondate,
(SELECT amount FROM orders_interactions  LEFT JOIN categories WHERE order=o.order AND category=3) as amount,
DATEDIFF((select date from orders_interactions  LEFT JOIN categories where order=o.order AND category=3),o.date) as elapseddays
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.idClient=o.idClient
```

Being this a simplified example of a much more complex query, I would like to know the recommended approaches for a query like this one, taking into account query times, and readability.

As the example shows, I had to repeat a subquery (the one with date), just to calculate a datediff, since I cannot directly reference the column 'completiondate'

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can `JOIN` instead of using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a left join.

```
SELECT o.order,
       o.date,
       o.producttype,
       oi.date completiondate,
       oi.amount,
       datediff(oi.date, o.date) completiondate
       FROM orders o
            LEFT JOIN orders_interactions oi
                      ON oi.order = o.order
                         AND oi.category = 3;
```

That doesn't *necessarily* perform better but there are good chances. For performance an index on `order_interactions (order, category)` might help in any case.

And if you consider it more readable is up to you. But at least it's less repetitive (Which doesn't necessarily translates to more performance. Just because an expression is repeated in a query doesn't necessarily mean it repeatedly calculated.)

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, it seems that my query simplification ended up being too simplified and that derived in a simple answer as well.
My subqueries also have joins inside, which at least as fas as I know, doesn't let me use a solution like yours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I might have found the answer.
In my opinion, it improves readability quite a bit, and in my real usage scenario, both profile and execution plans are way more efficient, and results are returned in less than 1/3 of the time.

My answer relies on using a SELECT inside the LEFT JOIN, hence, using a subquery as the JOINs 'input'.

```
SELECT
o.order,
o.date,
c.clienttype,
o.producttype,
tmp.date,
tmp.amount,
DATEDIFF(tmp.date,o.date) as elapseddays
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.idClient=o.idClient
LEFT JOIN (SELECT order,date,amount FROM orders_interactions oi LEFT JOIN categories ct ON ct.order=oi.order AND category=3) AS tmp ON tmp.order=o.order
```

The answer idea, and the explanation about how and why it works, came from this post: [Mysql Reference subquery result in parent where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932852/mysql-reference-subquery-result-in-parent-where-clause)